# Ist die Verwendung von „wir“ in wissenschaftlichen Veröffentlichungen heutzutage üblich?

Tags: grammatical-number, sentence-structure

Ob richtig oder nicht, findet man oft in auf Englisch geschriebenen wissenschaftlichen Veröffentlichungen das erste Pronomen in Plural *we*, selbst wenn es um eine Arbeit mit nur einem Autor geht:

**Fragen:**

- Ist das im Deutschen auch üblich?
- Ist das richtig?
- Welchen Eindruck übt ein Text mit Sätzen wie

  > *Ich habe X und Y (…) durchgeführt*

  anstatt

  > *Wir haben  X und Y (…) durchgeführt*

  auf den Leser (einen Fachmann/eine Fachfrau) aus?

Comment: Wenn *ich* eine wissenschaftliche Ausarbeitung mache, zu der *ich* Untersuchungen durchgeführt habe, zu denen *ich* Ergebnisse habe, so kennzeichne ich solche auch so. Wenn *ich* herausfinde, dass Fische fliegen können, warum sollte ich schrieben, dass *man* herausfand, dass Fische fliegen können. Beziehe ich mich aber auf die Arbeit eines anderen ("Im Unterricht zeigte der Lehrer ein Experiment. Es zeigte sich, dass Fische fliegen können."), so wäre es natürlich falsch, die 'ich'-Form zu verwenden.

Comment: @Em1 In einer seriösen wissenschaftlichen Ausarbeitung versucht der Autor, die Dinge nicht aus seiner Sicht zu schildern, sondern Fakten wiederzugeben. Möchte ich als Autor an irgendeiner Stelle mich besonders erwähnen, so geschieht dies beispielsweise mit dem Satz: "Nach Sicht des Autors ist es ...". Das von dir beschriebene Vorgehen ist unnötig (dein Name steht ja auf / unter der Arbeit) und lässt es an der notwendigen persönlichen Distanz mangeln. Eine wissenschaftliche Ausarbeitung hat nichts mit mir persönlich zu tun, sondern nur mit den Fakten, die ich betrachte.

Comment: @Em1 Um auf dein Beispiel einzugehen, wenn ich herausfinde, dass Fische fliegen können, würde ich dies in einer wissenschaftlichen Arbeit möglicherweise so ausdrücken: "Im Laufe der Arbeit wurde gezeigt, dass Fische fliegen können". Anstatt: "Ich habe herausgefunden, dass Fische fliegen können."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Die in Betracht kommenden Pluralformen sind:

- **Pluralis Auctoris** (Autorenplural)
  *Hier wird die Pluralform entweder gewählt, um das Mitwirken eines Teams an der wissenschaftlichen Arbeit zum Ausdruck zu bringen, oder um den Leser (bzw. das Auditorium) in die Gedankenführung einzubeziehen.*
- **Pluralis Modestiae** (Bescheidenheitsplural)
  *Dieser Plural wurde zur Vermeidung der Ich-Form eingesetzt, um dadurch bescheiden zu wirken.*

Es ist unbestritten, dass man, wenn das Ergebnis einer wissenschaftlichen Arbeit eines ganzen Teams veröffentlicht wird, über dieses Team im Pluralis Auctoris reden kann (und sollte). Anders sieht es bei einer Veröffentlichung der Arbeit einer Einzelperson aus. Hier ist ein Pluralis Modestiae nicht falsch, aber zunehmend unüblich geworden.

Die Leitfäden für das Abfassen wissenschaftlicher Arbeiten, die von den meisten Hochschulen oder deren Fakultäten veröffentlicht werden, unterscheiden sich, was Empfehlungen über die Verwendung des Pluralis angeht. Hier zwei stellvertretende Beispiele für das Spektrum der Ansichten:

> - **Keine Ich-Form!**
> - **Als überholt gilt:**
>
>   - das anonyme „Wir“, pluralis majestatis oder auch der pluralis modestiae (Ausnahme eine Autorengemeinschaft)
>   - das ebenso anonyme „man“
>   - die Schilderung der eigenen Ansichten in der dritten Person, z.B. „der Verfasser ist der Meinung, dass ...“

<sup>Marketing & Management: Leitfaden zum wissenschaftlichen Arbeiten. Univ. Hannover</sup>

> Unüblich geworden sind die Versionen "der Verfasser" und das den Leser vereinnahmende "wir". Gebräuchlich ist lediglich noch der Pluralis modestiae (Plural der Bescheidenheit, auch Pluralis auctoris, Autorenplural, genannt), vor allem in Vorworten und mündlichen Vorträgen: "wir" steht hier für "meine Mitarbeiter und ich". In der neueren Literatur trifft man ansonsten im Allgemeinen auf das unpersönliche "man", jedoch sollte man sich auch nicht scheuen, "ich" zu sagen, wo man "ich" meint.

<sup>Das Anfertigen einer wissenschaftlichen Arbeit. Univ. Göttingen</sup>

Möchte man den Pluralis Modestiae/Auctoris benutzen, dann sollte man darauf achten, dass der Stil konsequent über die gesamte Arbeit gleich bleibt. Ein Wechsel zwischen Pluralis und der Ich-Form sollte vermieden werden.

Comment: Sehr ausführlich. Andere Ansicht, die wenigstens für Englisch-Satzbau auch im akademischen Kontext ist eine weitere Modestie: dass es in der Arbeit einen Fehler geben könnte und dass der Autor (wenn es nur einen gibt) ganz für den selbigen verantwortlich sei. Mit *Passiv-* und *Pluralsatzaufbau* übertrüge man Verantwortlichkeiten. Aber gut zu wissen, dass es in Detuschen anders ist.

Comment: Was soll man denn der Uni Hannover zufolge machen. Bleibt ja nur Passiv. Meine Forschung ist passiv. Oh, ops...meine Forschung ist ja dann auch no no.

Comment: Noch was... man? Das kann ich mir nicht vostellen. "In dieser Arbeit untersucht man den Effekt von Smartphonebildschirmlicht auf Zimmerplanzen. Dazu hat man eine Testkultur von Grünlilien ....". Wir halten das für die schlechteste aller Varianten.

Comment: @Emanuel: diese beiden Gedanken sind mir auch durch den Kopf geschossen, als ich die beiden Anleitungen gelesen habe. --- Ich - Wir - Man  Die Verfasser ---  alles unüblich. Wie soll denn dann noch geschrieben werden? ;)

Comment: Oder immer mit dem Objekt selbst als Subjekt... "Der Versuch hatte das Ziel...", "Diese Arbeit möchte herausfinden..." , "Die Auswertung ergab..." die bsherige Forschung lässt einiges zu wünschen übrig" ... geht überraschend gut und ist ein bisschen wie Alice im Wunderland, wo Sachen allerhand machen ;)

Comment: Ich habe mehrfach festgestellt, dass das" ICH" hierzulande die beinahe diktatorisch erzwungene Form ist, die auch ich, im Kontrast zu fast allen meinen Vorbildern, zu verwenden genötigt wurde.

Answer (score 5):

In deutsch Fachbüchern in meinem Gebiet (Mathematik) wird relativ häufig im Plural geschrieben. Dabei meint der Autor (wenn es nur einer ist) typischerweise nicht sich selbst, sondern "sich und den Leser". Das funktioniert sehr gut in Passagen wie "wir sehen an dieser Stelle…", "Wir betrachten nun…". An Stellen, die offensichtlich nur den oder die Autoren meinen, wie z.B. "ich/wir haben X durchgeführt…" habe ich noch nie den Plural bei Einzelautoren gesehen. Deutsche Fachartikel lese ich in meinem Bereich fast gar nicht und kann dazu nichts sagen…

Comment: Das ist richtig, bezieht sich aber nicht auf die Frage. Da die Autoren der Fachbücher nur wiedergeben, was vor vielen Jahren jemand herausgefunden hat. Sie haben dazu keine eigenen Experimente durchgeführt um es zu beweisen. Sie gehen nur Schritt für Schritt alles durch, was man schon weiß. Und nimmt den Leser mit, denn der Leser "soll ja das folgende Beispiel betrachten". Deine Antwort stimmt auch für Fachartikel, da sie in diegleiche Kategorie fallen.

Answer (score 2):

Eine seriöse wissenschaftliche Veröffentlichung sollte sich von einem Erlebnisbericht unterscheiden. Deshalb wird dabei im Deutschen oft anstatt

> Ich / Wir habe(n) X und Y (...) durchgeführt

das neutrale

> Es wurden X und Y (...) durchgeführt

verwendet.

Das "Wir", welches von einer einzelnen Person genutzt wird, ist mir persönlich noch nie untergekommen, und würde auch äußerst seltsam wirken. Selbst wenn der ein oder andere Autor es verwenden würde, wäre das sehr ungewöhnlich.

Die Wirkung von "Wir" anstatt "Ich" ist klar die, dass dem Leser die Ergebnisse der wissenschaftlichen Arbeit gefestigter erscheinen, da diese nicht auf der Einschätzung einer einzelnen Person beruhen, und Irrtümer damit weniger wahrscheinlich. Dies ist auch ein Grund, das neutrale "Es" zu verwenden: Hier wird komplett vom eigenen Urteilsvermögen abgesehen. Es wird vorgegeben, für die gewonnenen Erkenntnisse nur die Faktenlage berücksichtigt zu haben:

> Es hat sich herausgestellt

anstatt

> Ich / Wir haben herausgefunden

Comment: This is what makes translations of scientific articels between English and German very difficult. Though it must said that  the strict use of the passive in german texts makes them often not easily readable.

Comment: @Ingo Vorallem die Geisteswissenschaftler schaffen es unglaublich verstarkste Sätze zu bauen. Bei den Naturwissenschaftlern wird es nur grauenhaft langweilig.

Comment: This is interesting, I was always taught to use the passive in high school when writing practical reports for science classes.